# $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$: standardising a random variable, or standardising a *normal* random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I frequently see it written in textbooks that "we standardise random variables by the computation $\dfrac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$". But my understanding is that the computation $\dfrac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$ only standardises **normal** random variables (so that it has a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$), right? Other random variables would require different computations to standardise them, and, even then, standardisation often is not possible for random variables of some types of distributions, right? Or do I have a misconception here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standardization will make every random variable (that has two moments) have mean $0$ and variance $1.$ On the other hand, would an exponential random variable with mean zero and variance one be standard? It is a question of language, not of mathematics.

Comment: Hi Igor. To make the english more precise, I think you should replace the "which" in "which has two moments" with "that": "The standardization will make every random variable (that has two moments) have mean $0$ and variance $1$." It's a subtle distinction, but it makes your claim more precise and clearer.

Comment: What do you mean that it is a question of language and not mathematics? I don't understand what you mean by this. Are you saying that, unlike normal random variables, we don't have a concept of 'standardised' for exponential random variables, and so we must define one if we wish to apply such a concept?

Comment: What I mean is that we call an $N(0, 1)$ gaussian the "standard normal", but the shift and scale of an exponential r.v. is not even exponential, but does have mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So we don't have a canonical definition of 'standardised' for exponential random variables, and so we must define one if we want to apply such a concept?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes, correct. Same for even variables which stay in the same family (like uniform, though unlike exponential). On the other hand, in the "usual" applications (machine learning) people are happy to use "standard scalers", because it guarantees that you are comparing apples with apples.